# JQuery Form Wizard Plugin - Chrome does not hide previous steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, formwizard, jquery-form-wizard

I have a form (using JQuery plugin Form Wizard from thecodemine.org) that works with Firefox. In Firefox when you hit "next" it hides the previous step and shows the next one. In Chrome it does not hide the previous step. Chrome does not give any Javascript error.

This is not a general problem with Chrome and Form Wizard. It is one specific to my implementation.

I created a test form for you to check this error: http://www.energyjustice.net/map/test2.html

I'm using Jquery UI 1.8.7 and Form Wizard 3.0.5.

Comment: I would guess it is the `visible` value in `outAnimation:  { position: "absolute", visibility: "visible", display: "block" },`

Comment: I don't think that has any impact.  I think the outAnimation refers to the fade-out of the step.  I tried making it "hidden" without impact.  

My guess is there is an html problem with divs and tables.  But I really don't know.

Comment: Looks like I need to use <div> instead of <span> for each step.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, using for each step. Looks like it has to be a block element, adding `style="display:block;"` to fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, adding

```
.step {
  display: block;
}
```

to my css made it work in chrome.